# Android widget sizing problems

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, tablet

The problem I am having with the widget is that it is fine on a normal size screen device but when i put it on my tablet the size changes to something different and not to the specified size.  The tablet is 7" and the problem mostly shows in Landscape.  This code is the same as the normal size and I do have them in the respective folders e.g. /large-land.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="100dp" 
android:background="@drawable/widgetbackground">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageButtonWeather"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:src="@drawable/hot"
    />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/weatherDisplay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButtonWeather"
android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my widget provider

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:minHeight="100dp" 
 android:minWidth="250dp" 
 android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000" 
 android:initialLayout="@layout/carlow_weather_widget">


</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Best of luck!